# How to reset Web Application Or ControllerTypeCache in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, web-applications, controller

In my project need to add some plugins in runtime, after add plugin call `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()` this clear all cache and static variable in my project. when use new controllers in new plugin he MVC framework couldn't find the new controller types and couldn't instantiate the requested controller.

While debugging this problem, i found "ControllerTypeCache" that MVC framework use it to cache controller types. ControllerTypeCache fill when application start. I need to reset ControllerTypeCache at runtime.

It looks like force restart the application will lead to updating the ControllerTypeCache with the latest plugins installed.

**Is there any way to restart this cache or web application at runtime?**

Comment: I have same situation but with WebAPI, did you manage to find a solution ?